Selenium RemoteWebdriver handle "SaveAs" window
As I read in multiple threads, there isn't a direct way of handling the "SaveAs" type of window directly using the Selenium's RemoteWebDriver, but what way are you using in this case?
I have an automation built in UiPath, using c# and selenium. Tried with UiPath's object repository, but this doesn't work.

anything outside the DOM would need a robot-like framework to handle.  Seems like UiPath should be able to do that.  Include code you've tried.
